# Gostaria se tem como colocar o min e o max no css para limitar os numeros em uma input type number

Tags: javascript, html, css

Nome

```
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" required />

    <label for="age">Idade</label>
    <input id="age" type="number" name="Idade" ( min="0" max="100" ) - gostaria de saber se tem como colocar isso no css nessa input

    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A funçao `minmax` do CSS é usada juntamente com CSS Grids, e define um intervalo de tamanhos que varia do valor do primeiro parâmetro (`min`) ao valor do segundo (`max`).

Nesse aspecto, a resposta a sua pergunta é não, pois você está trabalhando com `atributos` de elementos HTML e não com o tamanho destes.

Entretanto, você pode restringir os valores aceitos pelo campo `input` através da utilização dos **atributos** `min` e `max`:

```html
<input id="age" type="number" name="Idade" min="0" max="100" />
```

Para saber mais sobre a funçao `minmax` veja a [página da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax).

E, para saber mais sobre os atritubos html **[min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/min)** e **[max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max)**:

Answer (score -3):

Para determinar o "min" e o "max" de um input "type number", basta adicionar dentro da tag input os atribustos min=" " e máx=" " com os respectivos valores. Ex:

<input type="number" min="1" max= >